# google geocoder service

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I'm trying to use Google geocoder service to get the coordinates of cities input by the user. However looks like there's some problem initializing the LatLng() object (latlngCity), and the map won't show up. The code is as following:

```js
var map;
var latlngCity;

function initialize() {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({'address': 'Lisbon, PT'}, function(results, status) {
      if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        latlngCity = results[0].geometry.location;
      }
  });


  var myMapOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlngCity,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
      myMapOptions);
}
```

For simplicity, I'm inserting the address city string myself. Variables map and latlngCity are globals. Is there anything wrong with this code? 
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the map creation code into the `geocode` callback (or alternatively create the map with some default position and then re-center the map inside the callback).

In your code, `latlngCity` is undefined by the time of map creation while `geocode` is still being executed (asynchronously).

Hope this makes sense. Otherwise I'll provide some code. Let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried to create the map inside the callback and it worked. The geocoder is now working fine. However, I'm now unable to create markers on the map. I declared the map without 'var' inside the callback. It was supposed to become global right? But when I define the map in the markers' options it never show up.

Comment: Where do you create the markers? It could well be the exact same problem - try setting the markers inside the `geocode` callback, after map creation.

Comment: That's it! I had to create the markers inside the callback. Thank you again.